# How to set default minimum width scaling in Electron

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, electron, electron-builder

Using React and Electron, resizing the browser window width below 980 pixels causes the page to be scaled down so that the content will always display 980 pixels wide and visible in the view port, no matter how tiny the viewport width gets.

In `main.dev.js`:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 640,
    height: 480
  });
```

The browser window will open with 640px width, but the content will be scaled down so that 980px is visible.  Where should this width setting be configured?  I don't mind the feature for smaller viewports, but I'd prefer to use standard responsive styling to manage how the content will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    minWidth: DesiredMinWidth,
    minHeight: DesiredMinHeight,
});
```

This should work, if you want to configure a max height or width just replace min with max.